# New PC, screen blacks out after 10-20 minutes

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, desktop-computer

About 2 weeks ago I bought a custom pc with parts chosen by me and help from some people, and got the employees at the store to build it for me.

At first everything ran smooth, games like skyrim and crysis were playing at just about fully capacity with no problems...after a couple of days, after about 10-20 minutes of playing, the screen would go black, the gpu fan would stop spinning and id have to reset the computer.

I turned down the specs on the games to see if it would help, and it did, but the same thing would still happen after a while.

I checked the gpu temperatures and they were where they are supposed to be when idle and when gaming, since at first I thought I bought a defective video card, but now im thinking it might be the psu since I read a review on it and it was pretty bad. Heres that the review said.

> "Thermaltake TR2 RX 750 W is, according to our methodology, a flawed
>   product that must be avoided at all costs. It can’t deliver its
>   labeled wattage at high temperatures, but this is not the worst of it:
>   ripple and noise level are way above the maximum allowed when you pull
>   80% or more from the unit’s labeled capacity (i.e., 600 W and above),
>   overloading your components (especially electrolytic capacitors from
>   the motherboard and video cards), which can cause your PC to present
>   an erratic behavior (crashes and random resets) and, under extreme
>   conditions, damage components."

which is why im here now asking if anyone has the slightest clue of what is going on.

PC SPECS:
asus p8z77-vlx motherboard
intel core i5 3570k 3.40ghz processor
8 gigs corsair vengeance ddr3 ram
nvidia geforce gtx 560 graphics card
thermaltake TR2 RX 750watt bronze certified 80 plus power supply unit

Comment: welcome to superuser, you may find the [editing help page](http://superuser.com/editing-help) useful. Try the buttons/icons/widgets just above the text edit box for quick shortcuts for quoting text etc

Answer (score 3):

Your graphics card, processor, cpu, hardrive, motherboard, and memory are drawing more power than the Thermaltake can handle supplying according to what you posted.  As the power supply works to supply power to everything, it puts out more heat than it can dissipate.  The heat that isn't dissipating potentially causes damage to the power supply.  Replace your power supply with an 800 watt one from a different vendor.  If the problem goes away, you have proven that the power supply was the issue.  Since you have a post stating it's the issue, there is a high probability this is the answer for your problem.  It's the same diagnosis you were given [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/342380-28-power-supply).

Answer (score 0):

From your description it does sound quite possible that the PSU is indeed the problem. Before you replace it I would do the following things:

1) Consider if it worked before. (for the 20+ minutes). If it did then why? Was the room cooler before?

2) Test with another PSU before buying a new one. (Even though a good PSU is **important**)

3) Cqlculate how much power you actually need. E.g. the gtx 560 should draw up to 116 watts. The i5 is rated at a 77 Watt TDP. Add all the those and buy a PSU whose max rated power is slightly bigger then that.  (Take care about the +12v rails)

If another PSU does not help then you can try three things:

1. Test each item in another known stable computer until you find the one which fails.
2. Swap items with known good ones in your own computer
3. Try a fresh windows install to make sure it is not a software problem.
   If you think this is a lot of work then you can always make a backup of the current system before trying this.